# SQL Bulk Copy Operation not captured by APM Agent

Tags: elasticsearch, apm, elastic-apm

We are using SQLBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync Method for writing data to tables, but these operations are not getting captured by Apm Agent.

Below is the APM Agent setup

`if (!Agent.IsConfigured) { var apmComponents = new AgentComponents(null, new ApmConfiguration(apmSettings), payloadSender: null); Agent.Setup(apmComponents); IDiagnosticsSubscriber[] subscribers = { new HttpDiagnosticsSubscriber(), new SqlClientDiagnosticSubscriber() }; Agent.Subscribe(subscribers); }`

Tried with adding package "Elastic.Apm.EntityFrameworkCore" but didn't work.